# Difference between widget and new widget in flutter

Tags: dart, widget, flutter

What is the difference in declaring **Widget**   and    **new  Widget**

example:

```
appBar: AppBar(... ),
appBar: new AppBar(... ),

title: Text('Hi'),
title: new Text('Hi'),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new` and in const context `const` have become optional recently.

So, there is no difference, Dart just assumes `new` or `const` (depending on the context) if the following identifier is a class with a default constructor (or a named constructor if you use `MyWidget.fooName()`)

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/optional-new-const.md